# Enviar comandos para um Batch com entrada de usuário

Tags: batch, cmd

> **Contexto:**
>   Tenho um **Batch que não posso alterar**, a função dele é listar alguns arquivos em um diretório específico, e depois que ele lista os arquivos ele fica esperando algum comando do usuário.
>
> **Problema:**
>   Gostaria de automatizar esse processo, mas sem mexer no batch original, ou seja, **enviar** esse **comando** que o batch está esperando **via outro batch com loop de 1 em 1 minuto.**

Procurando em alguns fóruns, encontrei algumas pessoas sugerindo o uso do pipe para enviar os comandos, mas não funciona na hora que o batch espera a entrada do usuário.

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma ideia de enviar o comando na hora que o batch espera pela entrada?

```
Exemplo do batch:    
Arquivos parados em Download    
Não há arquivos parados em Download

COMANDO :
```

Comment: Porque vc não cria 1 bat que faz tudo isso ?

Comment: Porque você não pode modificar o batch que espera entrada do usuário?
Minha ideia é mais ou menos assim o primeiro batch verfica um arquivo a cada 30 segundos para ver se lá tem a resposta do usuário tipo sim ou não e esse arquivo e alterado pelo segundo batch. Ai dentro de 30 segundos o primeiro batch vai ter uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente este bat tem um comando parecido com isso:

```
set /p comando=Comando:
```

isso aguarda que algo seja digitado. Se esse comando foi carregado, não dá pra pular depois. Nesse caso teria que ter um GOTO enviando o script para outro campo
mas isso deve ser digitado dentro do bat.

Ex:

```
goto Pular
set /p comando=Comando:
:Pular
```

nesse caso o comando "set /p comando=Comando:" seria ignorado

também tem como enviar uma informação para o bat
na hora de executá-lo. mas o bat carregaria ela como %1 %2 %3...
ex:

```
call teste.bat Fala1 Fala2 Fala3
```

Arquivo teste.bat: (se der errado, remova o sinal de "~" antes do numero).

```
set aa=%~1
set bb=%~2
set cc=%~3
Echo %aa% %bb% %cc%
pause >nul
```